# In Carousal image slider, photos appear only when clicked on the dot

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, slider

I have a carousal image slider by javascript. But when we reload the page, first image is not appearing. we can only see the dots (of the carousal). When we click on the dot, Slider works perfectly. [Screenshot of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INWxG.png)
[PLEASE READ THE LAST PART OF THE QUESTION]

The code is as follows

```
 <div class="automatic-slider">
 <div class="slideshow-container">
 <div class="mySlides fade">
 <div class="numbertext">1 / 10</div>
 <img src="1.jpg" style="width:100%"  >
 </div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
<div class="numbertext">2 / 10</div>
<img src="2.jpg" style="width:100%" >
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
<div class="numbertext">3 / 10</div>
<img src="3.jpg" style="width:100%" >
</div>

<!-- Next and previous buttons -->
<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>
<br>

<!-- The dots/circles -->
<div style="text-align:center">
<span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
<span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
<span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
</div>
</div>

                            **CSS**
.slideshow-container {
max-width: 1000px;
position: relative;
margin: auto;
}

.mySlides {
display: none;
}

.prev, .next {
cursor: pointer;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
width: auto;
margin-top: -22px;
padding: 16px;
color: white;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 18px;
transition: 0.6s ease;
border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
user-select: none;
}

.dot {
cursor: pointer;
height: 15px;
width: 15px;
margin: 0 2px;
background-color: #bbb;
border-radius: 50%;
display: inline-block;
transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}
          
                   **Javascript**
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

// Next/previous controls
function plusSlides(n) {
showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

// Thumbnail image controls
function currentSlide(n) {
showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
var i;
var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
  slides[i].style.display = "none";
}
for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
}
slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
```

I think its because of "display : none;" . But if it is not used, the images are shown below the others.
The first image should be shown when reloaded. Thats the plan.

Comment: do use bootstrap, it will make things easy for you. for carousel refer this https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp or this https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp This is infact the exact codes that i used to make this slider :(

Comment: just call your function "showSlides" on load of body tag as onload="showSlides(1)"

Comment: Yaayy!! it worked using onload . Thanks Sahyog :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add an attribute to body tag as

```
<body onload="showSlides(1)">
```

accept the answer if it helped. and close the question.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't set the color of the dot when it is active. Just add the css code below.

```css
.dot.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}
```